# Pandas Column containing Alphanumeric data compare with same column of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to compare 2 data frames with same columns but may be not equal in number of rows. my problem is one column which contain some typos like "KVA 2048/20-21", "KVA2048/20" with space and without space, "033", "33" I code small function to solve the comparison problem but from pandas to python loop a 2000 line data frame comparison took 5 min or so. Any hope from pandas?

My Function:

```
def inv_no_match(val1, val2):
    if val1 != val2:
        if type(val1) == type(val2) == str:
            val1 = val1.replace(" ", "").replace('\r', "").replace('\n', "")
            val2 = val2.replace(" ", "").replace('\r', "").replace('\n', "")
            if val1 != val2:
                try:
                    val1 = int(val1)
                    val2 = int(val2)
                except:
                    pass
                if val1 != val2:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
            else:

                return True
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['KVA 2048/20-21', 'KVA2049/20-21', 'KVA 2050/20-21\n', 'KVA2048/20-21']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['KVA2048/20-21', 'KVA2050/20-21']})
```

Prints:

```
               col1
0    KVA 2048/20-21
1     KVA2049/20-21
2  KVA 2050/20-21\n
3     KVA2048/20-21
            col1
0  KVA2048/20-21
1  KVA2050/20-21
```

Then you can clean the column first:

```
def clean_column(x):
    x = x.replace(" ", "").replace('\r', "").replace('\n', "")
    return x

df1['col1'] = df1['col1'].apply(clean_column)
df2['col1'] = df2['col1'].apply(clean_column)
```

And then do `.merge()`:

```
print( df1.merge(df2, on='col1') )
```

Prints:

```
            col1
0  KVA2048/20-21
1  KVA2048/20-21
2  KVA2050/20-21
```

---

Note: If you want to do merge on the first number for example, modify the `clean_column` function accordingly:

```
import re

def clean_column(x):
    first_num = re.search(r'(\d+)', x)
    if first_num:
        return int(first_num.group(1))
    else:
        return np.nan

df1['tmp'] = df1['col1'].apply(clean_column)
df2['tmp'] = df2['col1'].apply(clean_column)

print( df1.merge(df2, on='tmp') )
```